# Working on a python project and there are syntax errors never faced before

Tags: python

```
    def main_menu():
        print("WELCOME TO LIBRARY")
        print("What would you like to do?")
        option=print(input("1. New user \n 2. Existing user ")

        if option == 1:
            new_user()
        elif option == 2:
            old_user()
        else:
            print("please choose a correct value")
            main_menu()

    def new_user():
        print("new user")

    def old_user():
        print("Old user")
    main_menu()
```

Here is a picture of the error, it says syntax error missing ")" for function call and missing "else" for the first one at "if":

[image]

Comment: Count your parentheses.

Comment: Can you make any guess what `missing ")"` could mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line

```
option=print(input("1. New user \n 2. Existing user ")
```

is missing a closing `)`
it should be

```
option=print(input("1. New user \n 2. Existing user "))
```